# How do I fix the MATE Desktop Environment theme after installing it alongside Unity?

Tags: 16.04, mate

I've been using Unity for as long as I can remember. However, I was open to try something new. I went for the [MATE Desktop Environment](http://mate-desktop.com/).

I installed it using `sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment` and to be honest, it didn't look *anything* like this:

[image: MATE Desktop]

Instead, I got something that looked like some sort of mutation of Windows 98. How can I get MATE to look like it does when installed fresh?

Comment: A description of how to install MATE without mentioning the `ubuntu-mate-desktop` package? Not very useful, IMO.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson this is about getting just the DE, it's indeed not a full Ubuntu MATE install

Comment: Ok, I see. Why make it easy when it's possible to complicate it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the good old [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/), went to *Appearance* > *Theme* > *Theme*, chose *Ambiance*, and then clicked on *Icons* and chose *ubuntu-mono-dark* and my Unity looked like the way it always had again.

Then, it was time to work on MATE. I installed `mate-desktop-environment-extras` which installed a few extra things, but can most likely be omitted. I opened Unity Tweak Tool and I tried a few themes. *They did not work*, which was because this is MATE, not Unity and it uses a different way of theming, or somehting.

I had more luck with the MATE Control Center, which looked like this...

[image: MATE Control Center]

Until I found *Appearance* under *Look and Feel*. I changed the theme to *Custom* and it all looked a lot better. I also changed the background to 'Ubuntu MATE Cold'.

[image: Various programs]

Yay! It works! It looks great now and it's superfast.